# Youtube API - onBehalfOfContentOwner value?

Tags: youtube-api

When using this parameter in the Youtube APIs. I am unable to determine the value for 22onBehalfOfContentOwner. I tried using the user id specified for the channel under:

https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced

The channel ID matches the channel I am going for. But I can't seem to be get ContentOwner right. Where can I find the right value to be used in this parameter.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%2C%22managedByMe%22%3Atrue%2C%22onBehalfOfContentOwner%22%3A%22c4rG0MP16xnAhMRJ4UWxTw%22%7D#usage

I have the Content Manager Access for this channel and I am using my credentials to authenticate with the API.

```
"message": "The specified content owner account was not found.",
```

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?